# How can i set my image as background on my tkinter digital clock?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to have my digital clock on top of the background. Currently the time is displaying above the image that im using

How should i set up this code? This is what i have come up with so far

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time

root=Tk()
root.title("Klocka")
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.iconbitmap('klocka.ico (1).ico')
root.geometry('300x200+50+50')


canvas=Canvas(root,width=300,height=140)
image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\\Users\\frass\\Desktop\\python projekt\\strand123.png"))

canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=image)
canvas.pack()

def present_time():
    display_time = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    digi_clock.config(text=display_time)
    digi_clock.after(200,present_time)

digi_clock = Label(root, font=("Times New Roman",50),activebackground="white",fg="black")
digi_clock.pack()

present_time()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `digi_clock.place(x=150, y=70, anchor="c")` to place the clock text on top of the center of the canvas.  However the background of the label is not transparent and so it is suggested to use `canvas.create_text(...)` to show the clock inside the canvas instead and then use `canvas.itemconfigure(...)` to update the clock.

Comment: Ok i fixed the digi_clock.place so it is now showing on top of the image.

Regarding the canvas.create and itemconfig im not really sure what values i should put in there of if that would do the trick, can you elaborate? Just to let you know im a complete beginner to this and just trying to learn :)

What should i do if i would like to remove the white background and just show the numbers of the clock?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `place()` instead of `pack()` to place the clock on top of the center of the canvas:

```py
digi_clock.place(x=150, y=70, anchor="c")
```

[image]

However the background of the clock label is not transparent.

You can use `canvas.create_text()` instead to show the clock and use `canvas.itemconfigure()` to update the clock:

```py
...
def present_time():
    display_time = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    # update the clock text
    canvas.itemconfigure("clock", text=display_time)
    root.after(200, present_time)

# clock text
canvas.create_text(150, 70, font=("Times New Roman",50), anchor="c", tags="clock")

present_time()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]